# how to replicate motor signal from flight controller among multiple motors?

Tags: flight-controller, esc, electronics

i would like to build a tailsitter and fly it with a flight controller such as ardupilot.  ardupilot seems to support [single/dual airplane motor configurations, or standard copter rotor layouts](https://ardupilot.org/plane/docs/guide-tailsitter.html#vectored-and-non-vectored).

however, i'd like the tailsitter to have multiple motors in line with the wings

something like this

### (not supported by ardupilot?)

(1)
[image]
or this

(2)
[image]

i dont think ardupilot actually supports either of those, but it does appear to support [this one](https://ardupilot.org/plane/docs/guide-tailsitter.html#single-dual-motor-tailsitter):

### (supported by ardupilot)

(3)

[image]

## Question:

is it possible to use the configuration in image (3) above, but simply replicate the signal to each left/right motor to get left/right pairs of motors as in image (1) (that flies and hovers well)?

if so, how could i go about it?  i'm assuming i'd still need an ESC per motor.  but would i also need to boost the signal coming from the flight controller if it's getting shared? or is there some better/correct way to go about this?

would there be issues with feedback from the motors to the ESC back to the flight controller?

[also asking at ardupilot](https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/tailsitter-3-motors-in-line-with-wing/99221)